# how to open a network folder in dired?

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows

Unfortunately, I'm stuck on Windows.
I have a network folder under this PC. Is there a way to navigate into it with dired without mounting it as another drive?

[image: THIS_PC]

Answer (score 1):

If the remote directory is not mapped to a drive letter, you can use `dired`, with the UNC path replacing backslashes with forward slashes, e.g. if in explorer the path is `\\server\share` the sequence of command in [@Drew answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61342/11725) becomes

```
C-x d
Dired (directory): 
Dired (directory): //server/share RET
```

Comment: not exactly the answer to my question. It does allow to access the network if you know the network address, which is something that I didn't know. Unfortunately, I cannot get the address due to the safety protocols.

Comment: @A_P you don't need the addres, `server` is the server name

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the usual Dired command (`dired`, bound to `C-x d`).

At the prompt for a directory, just enter the drive name that you want (which can be a network folder), followed by `:/`. For example:

```
C-x d
Dired (directory): 
Dired (directory): d:/ RET
```

---

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([download](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)) then you can also get a buffer that lists all of your MS Windows drives, which you can navigate through Dired.  Command **`diredp-w32-drives`** (bound to **`:/`** in Dired, but usable from anywhere) gives you a Dired buffer listing your drives.

Comment: This doesn't work with network folder.

Comment: @A_P: It should, if shell command `net use` works on your system. That works for network folders. `diredp-w32-drives` uses that shell command.